# In Python, how to rerun subprocess if error come and return value other than 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

In subprocess, if CMD throws an error in bash(other than 0 return, then want to retry again after 5mins

subprocess.call(CMD, shell=True)

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What have you attempted to solve this?

Comment: Please (re-)read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users . For example, what happened when you tried putting `python retry subprocess` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+retry+subprocess)? When I do that, I get the linked duplicate as the first result. This is apparently the 16th question you have asked on Stack Overflow so far, so you should know better by now.

Comment: Hi, I have googled and also try to search on StackOverflow. But what I found is retry if timeout of the subprocess. But what I need is to retry if return value is other that 0 (success).